# Rails - Devise - Routes issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise, routes

I'm trying to get devise set up and running in my app but I've hit the wall with it.

I'm seeing the this error message when i try

> Routing Error
>   No route matches {:controller=>"devise/clubs"}

Now the URL in my browser is

`http://localhost:3000/users/sign_up`

but I get the above, so I don't know where `"devise/clubs"` is coming from.

Now my routes file looks like so

```
Mess::Application.routes.draw do
 devise_for :users 

 resources :news , :clubs    
 root :to => "clubs#index" 
end
```

When I run rake routes I see

```
        new_user_session GET    /users/sign_in(.:format)       devise/sessions#new
            user_session POST   /users/sign_in(.:format)       devise/sessions#create
    destroy_user_session DELETE /users/sign_out(.:format)      devise/sessions#destroy
           user_password POST   /users/password(.:format)      devise/passwords#create
       new_user_password GET    /users/password/new(.:format)  devise/passwords#new
      edit_user_password GET    /users/password/edit(.:format) devise/passwords#edit
                         PUT    /users/password(.:format)      devise/passwords#update
cancel_user_registration GET    /users/cancel(.:format)        devise/registrations#cancel
       user_registration POST   /users(.:format)               devise/registrations#create
   new_user_registration GET    /users/sign_up(.:format)       devise/registrations#new
  edit_user_registration GET    /users/edit(.:format)          devise/registrations#edit
                         PUT    /users(.:format)               devise/registrations#update
                         DELETE /users(.:format)               devise/registrations#destroy
              news_index GET    /news(.:format)                news#index
                         POST   /news(.:format)                news#create
                new_news GET    /news/new(.:format)            news#new
               edit_news GET    /news/:id/edit(.:format)       news#edit
                    news GET    /news/:id(.:format)            news#show
                         PUT    /news/:id(.:format)            news#update
                         DELETE /news/:id(.:format)            news#destroy
                   clubs GET    /clubs(.:format)               clubs#index
                         POST   /clubs(.:format)               clubs#create
                new_club GET    /clubs/new(.:format)           clubs#new
               edit_club GET    /clubs/:id/edit(.:format)      clubs#edit
                    club GET    /clubs/:id(.:format)           clubs#show
                         PUT    /clubs/:id(.:format)           clubs#update
                         DELETE /clubs/:id(.:format)           clubs#destroy
                    root        /                              clubs#index
```

In form for creating the link i have

```
<%= link_to 'Sign up as User', new_user_registration_path %>
```

Routes tells me

```
    new_user_registration GET    /users/sign_up(.:format)       devise/registrations#new
```

It looks alright from the rake routes dump.

I've tried different variations in my routes.rb but I cant get this to work. I'm using rails 3.2.2 and ruby 1.8.7. Stepping up in the ruby version is not an option. (Host provider uses these two versions)

I checked the docs for devise, maybe I need to step down a version?? This is my first rails app so I'm learning by doing.

In my gem file I have:

```
gem  "devise"
```

So it is the latest 2.1.2 version!!

Any help, tips are greatly appreciated.

Logs from the console look like so

> Started GET "/users/sign_up" for 127.0.0.1 at Sun Sep 02 12:54:01 +0200 2012
>   Processing by Devise::RegistrationsController#new as HTML
>     Rendered devise/shared/_links.erb (0.7ms)
>     Rendered devise/registrations/new.html.erb within layouts/application (4.0ms)
>     Rendered application/_default_navigation.html.erb (1.4ms)
>   Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 35ms
>
> ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches {:controller=>"devise/clubs"}):
>     app/views/application/_default_navigation.html.erb:2:in 
>   `_app_views_application__default_navigation_html_erb___767051374_2180756000' 
>     app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:32:in`
>   _app_views_layouts_application_html_erb___31524913_2182039900'
>
> Rendered /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.2.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/routing_error.erb within rescues/layout (0.4ms)

Comment: Did you restart the rails app after adding Devise ? What are the logs before the routing error ? they may help to identify what happens when you click on the `new_user_registration` link.

Comment: I did restart with the changes but no joy. Logs from console are

Comment: Logs from console are now posted above!

Comment: The trace shows that the problem is in the partial  _default_navigation.html.erb . You should look into this file, or post it if can't figure what the problem is.

Comment: Yep thats it,thanks Baldrick. The troublesome line is <li><%= link_to(t('menuitem.home'), { :controller => "clubs", :action => "index" }) %></li>. Im abit bemused as to why this causes the problem. Need to play around with different variations.

Comment: That's strange, I don't see why Devise is messing with that. Nevertheless, you could rewrite it like that: `<li><%= link_to(t('menuitem.home'), clubs_path) %></li>`

Comment: Yep i meant to write back, the above works!! The other way screws up!! Thanks for the help!!

Comment: I have the same issue, but i have ```link_to('My questions', {:controller => 'questions', :action => 'index', :self => "1"})``` outputting ```No route matches {:controller=>"devise/questions", :self=>"1"}```. I can't use questions_path because i need an extra parameter.